# SQL Server Trigger To Copy Data From Columns Of Inserted Row In One Table To Rows Of Another Table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a webform that takes a users input into various fields and places them into a table as individual columns. I need to then take this row of data and copy the data in the columns into a another table as rows. The columns in the first table are associated with an id in the second table (the id is for other purposes not related to the tables and are a static set).

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this so I'm sure my description up above was not very clear. Here is a simplified example:

**Table 1**

```
street_address | city | state | zip
```

*TRIGGER*

**Table 2**

```
street_address | 1  
city | 2  
state| 3  
zip | 4
```

If one of the columns in table 1 is left blank, it should not create a row in table 2 at all.

Again, the id's that are used in table 2 are already set (that is, every column from table 1 is going to matched up to a predetermined id in table 2).

Any help with this would be great. I'm sorry if I didn't explain it all to well. I will clear up questions as they arise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your trigger needs to `UNPIVOT` from the `INSERTED` table into another table. Keep in mind that you will need to cast out all of the columns in the select list to the length of the longest column. Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e361/3)

```
SELECT colName, value
FROM(
  SELECT 
     street_address
    ,CAST(city AS VARCHAR(100)) AS city
    ,CAST(state AS VARCHAR(100)) AS state
    ,CAST(zip AS VARCHAR(100)) AS zip
  FROM Table1
)AS p
UNPIVOT(
  value FOR colName IN(street_address, city, state, zip)
)AS unpvt
```

Comment: This is great. I am getting my first table to look like what I need it to look like finally. I have a question though. How do I get the id associated with each column to work with this unpivoted table? The ids are constant (that is street_address with always have an id of 1). Should I create another table with the column names and ids and link it to this somehow? Is it better to just manually input all the ids somewhere in the code you already provided? Thank you again for your help thus far.

Comment: Actually, I got this. I created a table with the column name and unique id for that column and linked it to the table returned in the query you gave me. Thank you for all the help.